# SQL- UNION : How to UNION 4 SELECT of unmatched column by Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union, multi-select

```
SELECT 'ABC-D Header1' As Seq1
UNION
SELECT 'ABC-D Header2' AS seq2
UNION
SELECT  ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4 ' AS seq3
UNION
SELECT 'ABC-D Tail' AS Seq4
ORDER BY SEQ1 ASC

 OUTPUT:  
 ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4
 ABC-D Header1
 ABC-D Header2     
 ABC-D Tail

EXPECTED RESULT :

ABC-D Header1
ABC-D Header2
ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4
ABC-D Tail
```

Could anyone help me how UNION works internally, I am dealing with hardcoded values, which should come in two rows ( Header1, Header2) followed by data and Tail part. 
I have tried ASC and DESC as well, nothing seems working in giving exact result as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the `order by` and it works

Comment: Resultsets and tables have no order by definition. If you want rows in a particular order, there must be an order by clause that uses columns that reflect your desired order. This is a basic concept you need to learn and understand in order by to successful in sql. Do not be mislead by any order you might see using small sets of data or by using a machine that does not experience any resource contention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add another column for the required ordering

```
SELECT 'ABC-D Header1' As Seq1, s = 1
UNION
SELECT 'ABC-D Header2' AS seq2, s = 2
UNION
SELECT  'ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4 ' AS seq3, s = 3
UNION
SELECT 'ABC-D Tail' AS Seq4, s = 4
ORDER BY s ASC
```

EDIT:
If you do not wish to have the `s` in result, use `cte` or `derived table`

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 'ABC-D Header1' As Seq1, s = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 'ABC-D Header2' AS seq2, s = 2
    UNION
    SELECT  'ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4 ' AS seq3, s = 3
    UNION
    SELECT 'ABC-D Tail' AS Seq4, s = 4
)
SELECT  Seq1
FROM    CTE
ORDER BY s ASC
```

Comment: Thank you so Much , this worked, I never got an idea of adding one more col and sort.

Comment: @ShwetaReddy . . . Do not use `UNION` when `UNION ALL` is intended.  `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.

Comment: @Squirrel also in any way can we remove s in output? No rite, we just need to call only required column from front end correct ? or is there any way to hide 's'

Comment: @ShwetaReddy added the query

Answer (score 3):

You can use `VALUES` with position :

```
SELECT t.Header
FROM ( VALUES (1, 'ABC-D Header1'), 
              (2, 'ABC-D Header2'), 
              (3, 'ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4 '), 
              (4, 'ABC-D Tail'))
     ) t(Seq, Header)
ORDER BY seq;
```

Comment: @ShwetaReddy . . . This is the best solution.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff What makes this answer different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60501605/9071943)?

Comment: @Phong. . . It doesn't have Ordering column. That makes different.

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Sharma, As you can see, It doesn't need extra columns. Check online [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=471494c924364888d6b90f03613a8b89) Happy coding + 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Seq1
from
(
SELECT 'ABC-D Header1' As Seq1, number = 1
UNION
SELECT 'ABC-D Header2' AS seq2, number = 2
UNION
SELECT  'ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4 ' AS seq3, number = 3
UNION
SELECT 'ABC-D Tail' AS Seq4, number = 4
) a 
ORDER BY number ASC
```

Or you can also use **`Desired table`** like this way without redundant columns

```
SELECT Seq1
FROM(
 VALUES
 ('ABC-D Header1'),
 ('ABC-D Header2'),
 ('ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4 '),
 ('ABC-D Tail')
)v(Seq1)
```

[**Result here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=471494c924364888d6b90f03613a8b89)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it also. With `unpivot`.

```
select seq from 
(select convert(varchar(50), 'ABC-D Header1') as seq1
        , convert(varchar(50), 'ABC-D Header2') as seq2
        , convert(varchar(50),'ABC-D data1 data2..3..data4') as seq3
        , convert(varchar(50),'ABC-D Tail') as seq4) a
unpivot (seq for seq_order in ([seq1], [seq2], [seq3], [seq4])
) as b
```

[here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9d7cf531dadc5e2fe69b03204766e9aa)

The `convert` was used becuase without it the error was thrown that the seq3 conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help. Thanks for the up vote. Cheers!